# In react - once I change the value of the data in my API - how can I then re-render my component with the new data?

Tags: reactjs, axios, components, state, reload

I've tried to fix this with the useState hook but it still won't work - if I click the checkbox the first time the div will turn green, but when I untick it, it still stays green.

Here is my new code - please help

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
```

import './item.css'
import axios from 'axios';

const Item = ({ todo }) => {

```
const [tryThis, setTryThis] = useState(todo.complete)


const eventHandle = async () => {
    try {
        if(todo.complete == false) {
            const res = await axios.put(`todo/${todo._id}`, {
            complete: true,
        })
        // window.location.reload();
        setTryThis(true)
        console.log(res)
        } else {
            const res = await axios.put(`todo/${todo._id}`, {
            complete: false,
        })
        // window.location.reload();
        setTryThis(false)
        console.log(res)
        }
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
    }


const deleteTodo = () => {
    axios.delete(`todo/${todo._id}`)
    window.location.reload();
}

return (
    <li>
        <div className={!tryThis ? 'item' : 'item itemComplete'} >
        <div className='itemText'>
           <p>{todo.desc}</p>
        </div>
        <div className='itemInput'>
            <input type='checkbox' defaultChecked={todo.complete} onClick={() => eventHandle()} />
        </div>
        <div className='itemButton'>
            <button className='actualButton' onClick={() => deleteTodo()} >Delete</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </li>
)
```

}

export default Item

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'

import './item.css'

import axios from 'axios';


const Item = ({ todo }) => {


    const eventHandle = async () => {
        try {
            if(todo.complete == false) {
                const res = await axios.put(`todo/${todo._id}`, {
                complete: true,
            })
            window.location.reload();
            console.log(res)
            } else {
                const res = await axios.put(`todo/${todo._id}`, {
                complete: false,
            })
            window.location.reload();
            console.log(res)
            }
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
        }
    

    const deleteTodo = () => {
        axios.delete(`todo/${todo._id}`)
        window.location.reload();
    }

    return (
        <li>
            <div className={!todo.complete ? 'item' : 'item itemComplete'} >
            <div className='itemText'>
               <p>{todo.desc}</p>
            </div>
            <div className='itemInput'>
                <input type='checkbox' defaultChecked={todo.complete} onClick={() => eventHandle()} />
            </div>
            <div className='itemButton'>
                <button className='actualButton' onClick={() => deleteTodo()} >Delete</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </li>
    )
}

export default Item
```

I am new to programming and have been trying to build a  todo app using the MERN stack.

It's working fine except for one function. When a task is complete I want to tick the checkbox which then turns the parent div background green.

In order to make my changes happen instantly I'm using -

`window.location.reload();`

Without this the background doesn't go green until I manually hit refresh.

This code works for the moment but I'm worried that this isn't a good practice as every time I do anything the console clears as the whole page is reloaded.

Is there some way of just refreshing that particular component and not the entire page?

Thanks
[image]

Comment: You need to introduce **state** into your component and use `setState()` to update your component. React will then automatically re-render your component as needed. Please have a look at the [React docs or tutorial](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html). To introduce state in a modern React way use the [useState hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

Comment: Hi @Mushroomator thanks for getting back to me - I've tried to update it using useState() as you advised but I still can't get it to work - I've updated the question above with my new code - could you please show me how to fix it. Thank you